# swap the position of all content inside div using a Check Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can I switch the content via JavaScript or JQuery? I have content A and content B, where position A is next to envy and B is on the right, when I click the check box the content B will change to the left and content A to the right, and when I click again, it will change to like the beginning again.

This my snippet, I tried exchanging all div content between A and B. When I clicked on the check box, there will be all content in div A will exchange with div B.
but why does only the input form change? while the content doesn't change, can anyone help me?
is there something wrong with my code?

```js
function swap_content(conta,contb)
  {
    var tmp = document.getElementById(conta).value;
    document.getElementById(conta).value = document.getElementById(contb).value;
    document.getElementById(contb).value = tmp;
    var tdp = document.getElementById(text_id1).value;
    document.getElementById(text_id1).value = document.getElementById(text_id2).value;
    document.getElementById(text_id2).value = tdp;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://webapplayers.com/inspinia_admin-v2.8/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://webapplayers.com/inspinia_admin-v2.8/css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://webapplayers.com/inspinia_admin-v2.8/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">


<body>
    <div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-5" id="conta" style="background: red;">
                <div class="ibox ">
                    <div class="ibox-title">
                        <h5>
                            <input type="text" name="text_id1" id="text_id1" value="content A" >
                        </h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ibox-body">
                     <span style="color:white">
                     This is desc about Content A </span><br>

                     <img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/7254/7740405218_d3b9c5e839_h.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>

         <div class="col-lg-2">
            <div class="ibox ">
                <div class="ibox-title">

                    <div class="switch">
                        <div class="onoffswitch">
                            <input type="checkbox" checked class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="example1" onclick="swap_content('text_id1','text_id2')">
                            <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="example1">
                                <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                                <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-5" id="contb" style="background: blue">
            <div class="ibox ">
                <div class="ibox-title">
                    <h5>
                        <input type="text" name="text_id2" id="text_id2" value="content B" >
                    </h5>
                </div>
                <div class="ibox-body">
                    <span style="color:white">This is desc about Content B</span> <br>

                    <img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/1429/5164748081_b2e7e19108_b.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<script src="http://webapplayers.com/inspinia_admin-v2.8/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes, you can, but what have you tried? We expect that you'll do research and make an attempt first. Try a Google search for "swap content using JavaScript" and you'll find lots of things you can research.

Comment: 404 not found: Missing code attempt

Comment: @ScottMarcus i've add my snipet code

Comment: wait isn't this the same question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55932692/using-checkbox-to-swap-the-position-of-content-inside-div-element/55932943#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the input values change because that's all your code attempts to work with (`text_id1` and `text_id2`).

You had the right idea, but you really just need to swap the contents of `div id="conta"` and `div id="contb"`, but only form-field elements have a `value` property. `div` elements have either the [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) property (for getting/setting just the text within the element) or the [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property (for getting/setting text that contains HTML that needs to be parsed).

Lastly, don't use inline HTML event attributes, such as `onclick`. There are [a bunch of reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991) not to use this 25+ year old technique. Instead, do all your event binding in JavaScript - separate from your HTML.

```js
// Get reference to the checkbox and set up click event handler
var cb = document.getElementById("example1").addEventListener("click", swap_content);  

// Store references to the two div elements
var conta = document.getElementById("conta");
var contb = document.getElementById("contb"); 

function swap_content() {
  // Non-form field elements don't have .value, they have .innerHTML
  var tmp = conta.innerHTML;
  conta.innerHTML = contb.innerHTML;
  contb.innerHTML = tmp;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://webapplayers.com/inspinia_admin-v2.8/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://webapplayers.com/inspinia_admin-v2.8/css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://webapplayers.com/inspinia_admin-v2.8/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">


<body>
    <div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-5" id="conta" style="background: red;">
                <div class="ibox ">
                    <div class="ibox-title">
                        <h5>
                            <input type="text" name="text_id1" id="text_id1" value="content A" >
                        </h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ibox-body">
                     <span style="color:white">
                     This is desc about Content A </span><br>

                     <img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/7254/7740405218_d3b9c5e839_h.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>

         <div class="col-lg-2">
            <div class="ibox ">
                <div class="ibox-title">

                    <div class="switch">
                        <div class="onoffswitch">
                            <input type="checkbox" checked class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="example1">
                            <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="example1">
                                <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                                <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-5" id="contb" style="background: blue">
            <div class="ibox ">
                <div class="ibox-title">
                    <h5>
                        <input type="text" name="text_id2" id="text_id2" value="content B" >
                    </h5>
                </div>
                <div class="ibox-body">
                    <span style="color:white">This is desc about Content B</span> <br>

                    <img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/1429/5164748081_b2e7e19108_b.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<script src="http://webapplayers.com/inspinia_admin-v2.8/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
function swap_content(conta, contb) {
    var contentA = document.getElementById(conta).innerHTML;
    document.getElementById(conta).innerHTML = document.getElementById(contb).innerHTML;
    document.getElementById(contb).innerHTML = contentA;
}
```

**Note:** You need to pass the id's of div which contents you are willing to swap.
Change onlick function to `onclick="swap_content('conta','contb')"`